# Difference in Triax connector types

Tags: coax

What is the difference between TRB and TRC? What do they stand for? what are they referring to exactly? While we are on this subject, what are TRT, TTM, TRX, TRS? I have scoured the internet with no information at all. Everyone in this industry seems to know what these terms/types stand for and not a single datasheet bothers to explain it. I assumed it is different connections to the conductors, but doesn't seem like it. Can anyone give me a guide?

I have decyphered most other terms. 2/3 lug/slot (how many pegs are there), coax/twinax/triax, the not very obvious male/female (referring only to the innermost conductor, not the outer shell), but for the life of me, I cannot figure out this TRB, TRS thing (along with the other types). What does it even refer to?

I cannot just buy them and see them for myself, they are 1- very expensive, and 2- the difference may not be observable from the outside, especially when I don't even know what am I looking at. With very expensive equipment (B1500, completely custom probes (long-story, don't ask)), I can't just buy anything and cross my fingers. If I don't fry the equipment, at would at least not know what am I really measuring.

For context: I am looking for adapters and possibly coax cables. We will probably have to connect to BNC at some point before the DUT (I know, I am losing some of Triax's functionality). The specifics of the setup are irrelevant.

**Edit:** upon further digging, I may have found something (this is all still speculation). These names seem to refer to the connector's shape and maybe size (like BNC, thanks @peter bennet).

- TRT/TTM: These seem to be threaded connectors with different sizes.
- TRB: seem to be BNC-like, can be with 3 or 2 lugs/slots. Some
  brochures claim it is only 3 though.
- TRC: seem to be BNC-like, can only be only 2 lugs/slots. I can find
  only one product (on both mouser and Digikey)

If someone's from the industry and can confirm, that would be nice.

Comment: You're asking about coax connectors in the title, but then you list a bunch of *triax* connectors.

Comment: You are right. Within the confusion, I thought that triax is a type of coax at some point

Comment: A triax is just a coax with two independent shields.  They are used when you need better shielding effectiveness than a single shield provides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of these connector names, as far as I can tell, originate with Trompeter, a connector manufacturer that's now a subsidiary of Cinch Connectivity. If nothing else, their catalog seems to be the most useful source of information on these.

- **TRB** has the same outer dimensions as BNC and uses a bayonet lock, so it's the one you're likely most familiar with, since you say you use a B1500--these are the connectors used for the B1500 and B1505's SMUs (other than the HVSMU). TRB is available with 2, 3, or 4 bayonet lugs, as well as a push-on version that doesn't lock. Trompeter also calls this their "70 series".
- **TRT** is to TRB what TNC is to BNC. It's the same as TRB, but with a threaded locking system instead of bayonet; it has the same outer dimensions as TNC. Trompeter also calls this their "370 series".
- **TRS** and **TTM** are the triaxial equivalents of TPS (kind of a mini-BNC) and TCM (kind of a mini-TNC). They're basically the same as TRB and TRT, just shrunken a bit. Trompeter also calls these their 150 and 3150 series, respectively.
- **TRC** and **TRN** are, once again, the same thing, but larger this time; these have the same outer dimensions as C connectors (which are approximately the same size as N connectors). Trompeter calls them their 80 and 380 series, respectively.
- **Series 450** and **series 3450** connectors, which for some reason don't appear to have a three-letter name, seem to be even smaller than TRS and TTM, but I can't find any information on their dimensions. From the pictures I see, it seems to be about the size of micro-BNC.
- **TWBNC** and **TWTNC** are twinaxial connectors, not triaxial, but I figure they should get a mention too. They're the same size as BNC and TNC respectively, but have one pin and one socket inside instead of a pin and shields. Trompeter also calls them their 30 and 330 series.

I'm not certain, but I think the B1500's HVSMU connector might be a TRN connector. I'd actually been wondering that for some time, so it's good to stumble across what might be the answer.

---

Most information sourced from [Trompeter's catalog](https://web.archive.org/web/20221201014034/https://www.mavin.com/pdf/Trompeter%20Catalog.pdf), with some additional help from [this reseller's page](https://web.archive.org/web/20221018111708/https://isiconnectors.com/mfrs/trompeter/twinax.htm). Some dimensional information (on both the triax connectors and, for comparisons, more familiar coax connectors) was sourced from [Delta RF](https://www.deltarf.com/product-line).

Comment: This is it! thank you so much. I was in the process of piecing this together from scouring many datasheets. Got halfway there, but your description is 100 times better.

Comment: My research from belfuse.com and Trompeter datasheets says: TRC (lugs) TNS (threaded) use .531-.535" socket diameter and .625-24 threads (BJ883, BJ380, & BJ8O datasheets) aka 80 series. TRB (lugs) TRT (threaded) use .38" socket diameter and .4375-28 threading  (MIL-STD-348B specification) aka 70 series. TRS (lugs) TTM (threaded) use .295" socket diameter and 3/8-32 threading  (BJ152FL datasheet)  aka 150 series. Series 450 (aka series 3450, aka TRL/TRK/TCS) use .24" socket diameter and 5/16-32 threading (BJ457PP datasheet).

Answer (score -2):

You need to hone your internet skills. I googled TRB connector and found the following site: https://www.deltarf.com/trb. Attached to that site is a 6 page PDF specification for TRB connectors. I'm sure you can use google to find the rest.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. it talks about their OWN TRB, not TRB. check everything I am asking about and you will understand. Look up the others and try to tell me the difference. also notice that your link doesn't define what do these letters mean. It is half information. not good enough. confusing at best

Enough information means one could easily say: "Aha! for my very specific application, I would need this specific type because 1 2 3" is it material? direction? some RF properties? shape?! size? what is it?

Comment: @himura: the letters TRB may just be a designation the manufacturer chose - the letters may not have any meaning for people outside the company other than designating that particular style of connector - perhaps they are the designer's initals (as BNC is).

Comment: Interesting theory. I am looking at DigiKey part picker and you have a choice on the adapter series which includes TRB, TRC, along with the others. Maybe Digikey largely deals with one supplier (and that supplier is not Delta, the company in the link of this answer). Weird categorization. Still need to confirm before I let it to rest.

Comment: @himura Digikey fills in its parametric search with the information in the datasheet. If a part's datasheet says it's TRB, it gets marked as TRB. That said, I don't see anything different between the Delta TRB and any other TRB, though I haven't looked into it in much depth.